# Install yum packages on a mounted volume

Tags: yum

I have a Raspberry Pi with Pidora installed. I need to install a LAMP server. This is the scheme of the filesystem, with a mounted USB flash drive.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       2.1G  2.0G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        218M     0  218M   0% /dev
tmpfs           218M     0  218M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           218M  376K  218M   1% /run
tmpfs           218M     0  218M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           218M  160K  218M   1% /tmp
/dev/sdb1       7.5G  1.7G  5.8G  23% /mnt/ExternalDrive
/dev/mmcblk0p5   50M   23M   27M  46% /boot
```

The `/` partition has no space left, so I figured I could mount a USB flash drive in order to install `mysql`, `apache`, `php` and my website files there.

- Is that the best way to go in this situation?
- If so, how can yum packages be installed on a mounted volume?

Consider that reinstalling the OS is not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

You could move your '/home`,`/usr`and/or`/var`directories to the external drive then adjust your`/etc/fstab` so that they are mounted automatically.

Run `du -sh /` to work out the culprit directories - it may take some time to run.

`/dev/sdb1' shows up as using 1.7Gb.  You could shrink that partition to make space for the others.

Make sure that the new filesystems are `ext4` or `xfs` (not `NTFS` or `FAT32`).

Boot into single-user mode to do this work.

When you edit your `/etc/fstab` use `UUID=` or `LABEL=` entries as opposed to `/dev/sdb2` style. If you don't and insert another USB storage device at a later date, you could end up with different `/dev/sd??` names and neither `/var` or `/usr`/ will mount.